# NetAdapter command gives 'The data is invalid' message

Tags: powershell

I am trying to rename the Ethernet adapter after creating a VLAN in my script. It currently just creates a new `Ethernet x` as an adapter.

From what I can find online Get-NetAdapter should display all network adapters and Rename-NetAdapter should work, however I keep getting the following error:

[image]

Kind regards,
Tom

Comment: I wonder if your Powershell error is just the result of an underlying problem of some kind.
It might be worth to have a look in the Windows event viewer (eventvwr.exe) and checking the Application and System logs for any helpful errors.
You could also check the system file integrity by opening a command prompt as admin and typing 'SFC /scannow' (without the quotes).

Comment: Did you try `Get-NetAdapter -Name "*"`?

Comment: @Theo, same error message unfortunately. I'm going to check MonQ's suggestion.

Comment: @MondQ, nothing in the event viewer and the scan didn't find any integrity violations

Comment: Does the below WMIC query return any network adapters, or useful data?

wmic nic get AdapterType, Name, Installed, MACAddress, PowerManagementSupported, Speed

Comment: @MondQ, those outputs seem to be correct and normal

Comment: I've tried the `Get-NetAdapter` command on 5 computers and it works on every single one, except for the one I'm writing the script..

Comment: You could try to reinstall/update the Windows Management Framework, which installs/updates Powershell. Maybe that will help.
There are different installers for different operating systems.
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=54616